# HttpClient4 simulation Login always failed, Cookie does not work,

Tags: httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

the first request is suceess,but the second request is always redirected to Login page.
i use httpclient4.0.1.

```
public class HttpClientLoginTest {
    <!-- The configuration items-->
    private static String userName = "admin";
    private static String password = "12315";
    private static String redirectURL = "/manager/index.php";

    private static String LoginURL = "http://localhost/manager/login.php";

    private HttpResponse response;

    private static DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    <!-- the first request is login-->
    private void login() throws Exception {

        HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/manager/login.php");
        <!--  All the parameters post to the web site-->
        List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("gotopage", redirectURL));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dopost", "login"));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("adminstyle", "newdedecms"));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userid", userName));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pwd", password));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sm1", ""));

        httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));

        response = httpclient.execute(httpost);

        int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        System.out.println("Sending 'POST' request to URL : " + LoginURL);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
            <!-- print reponsebody-->
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response
                .getEntity().getContent()));

        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }

        System.out.println(result.toString());

        httpost.abort();

    }
    <!-- the second request-->
    private String getText(String redirectLocation) throws Exception,
            IOException {
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(redirectLocation);

        response = httpclient.execute(request);

        int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        System.out.println("request to URL : " + redirectLocation);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
            <!-- print reponsebody-->
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response
                .getEntity().getContent()));

        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }

        return result.toString();
    }

    public void printText() {
        try {
            login();
            getText("http://localhost/manager/index.php");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HttpClientLoginTest test = new HttpClientLoginTest();
        test.printText();
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }

}
```

here' log ! thank your very much!

```
Get connection for route HttpRoute[{}->http://localhost]
CookieSpec selected: best-match
Attempt 1 to execute request
Sending request: POST /manager/login.php HTTP/1.1
>> "POST /manager/login.php HTTP/1.1[EOL]"
>> "Content-Length: 94[EOL]"
>> "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8[EOL]"
>> "Host: localhost[EOL]"
>> "Connection: Keep-Alive[EOL]"
>> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.0.1 (java 1.5)[EOL]"
>> "Expect: 100-Continue[EOL]"
>> "[EOL]"
>> POST /manager/login.php HTTP/1.1
>> Content-Length: 94
>> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
>> Host: localhost
>> Connection: Keep-Alive
>> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.0.1 (java 1.5)
>> Expect: 100-Continue
<< "HTTP/1.1 100 Continue[EOL]"
<< "[EOL]"
Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
<< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
>> "gotopage=%2Fmanager%2Findex.php&dopost=login&adminstyle=newdedecms&userid=admin&pwd=12315&sm1="
<< "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[EOL]"
<< "Date: Sun, 02 Mar 2014 15:18:49 GMT[EOL]"
<< "Server: Apache/2.2.4 (Win32) PHP/5.2.4[EOL]"
<< "X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.4[EOL]"
<< "Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=kkjhvrbaoq2rbtk88f0nljaua2; path=/[EOL]"
<< "Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT[EOL]"
<< "Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0[EOL]"
<< "Pragma: no-cache[EOL]"
<< "Set-Cookie: DedeUserID=1; expires=Mon, 03-Mar-2014 15:18:49 GMT; path=/[EOL]"
<< "Set-Cookie: DedeUserID__ckMd5=e22b0794b6991249; expires=Mon, 03-Mar-2014 15:18:49 GMT; path=/[EOL]"
<< "Set-Cookie: DedeLoginTime=1393773529; expires=Mon, 03-Mar-2014 15:18:49 GMT; path=/[EOL]"
<< "Set-Cookie: DedeLoginTime__ckMd5=4e56d5c9755c8116; expires=Mon, 03-Mar-2014 15:18:49 GMT; path=/[EOL]"
<< "Content-Length: 932[EOL]"
<< "Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100[EOL]"
<< "Connection: Keep-Alive[EOL]"
<< "Content-Type: text/html; charset=gb2312[EOL]"
<< "[EOL]"
Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<< Date: Sun, 02 Mar 2014 15:18:49 GMT
<< Server: Apache/2.2.4 (Win32) PHP/5.2.4
<< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.4
<< Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=kkjhvrbaoq2rbtk88f0nljaua2; path=/
<< Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
<< Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
<< Pragma: no-cache
<< Set-Cookie: DedeUserID=1; expires=Mon, 03-Mar-2014 15:18:49 GMT; path=/
<< Set-Cookie: DedeUserID__ckMd5=e22b0794b6991249; expires=Mon, 03-Mar-2014 15:18:49 GMT; path=/
<< Set-Cookie: DedeLoginTime=1393773529; expires=Mon, 03-Mar-2014 15:18:49 GMT; path=/
<< Set-Cookie: DedeLoginTime__ckMd5=4e56d5c9755c8116; expires=Mon, 03-Mar-2014 15:18:49 GMT; path=/
<< Content-Length: 932
<< Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
<< Connection: Keep-Alive
<< Content-Type: text/html; charset=gb2312
Cookie accepted: "[version: 0][name: PHPSESSID][value: kkjhvrbaoq2rbtk88f0nljaua2][domain: localhost][path: /][expiry: null]". 
Cookie accepted: "[version: 0][name: DedeUserID][value: 1][domain: localhost][path: /][expiry: Mon Mar 03 23:18:49 CST 2014]". 
Cookie accepted: "[version: 0][name: DedeUserID__ckMd5][value: e22b0794b6991249][domain: localhost][path: /][expiry: Mon Mar 03 23:18:49 CST 2014]". 
Cookie accepted: "[version: 0][name: DedeLoginTime][value: 1393773529][domain: localhost][path: /][expiry: Mon Mar 03 23:18:49 CST 2014]". 
Cookie accepted: "[version: 0][name: DedeLoginTime__ckMd5][value: 4e56d5c9755c8116][domain: localhost][path: /][expiry: Mon Mar 03 23:18:49 CST 2014]". 
Connection can be kept alive for 5000 ms
<< "<html>[\r][\n]"
<< "<head>[\r][\n]"
<< "<title>DedeCMS[0xcc][0xe1][0xca][0xbe][0xd0][0xc5][0xcf][0xa2]</title>[\r][\n]"
<< "<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb2312" />[\r][\n]"
<< "<base target='_self'/>[\r][\n]"
<< "<style>div{line-height:160%;}</style></head>[\r][\n]"
<< "<body leftmargin='0' topmargin='0' bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>[\r][\n]"
<< "<center>[\r][\n]"
<< "<script>[\r][\n]"
<< "      var pgo=0;[\r][\n]"
<< "      function JumpUrl(){[\r][\n]"
<< "        if(pgo==0){ location='/manager/index.php'; pgo=1; }[\r][\n]"
<< "      }[\r][\n]"
<< "document.write("<br /><div style='width:450px;padding:0px;border:1px solid #DADADA;'><div style='padding:6px;font-size:12px;border-bottom:1px solid #DADADA;background:#DBEEBD url(/plus/img/wbg.gif)';'><b>DedeCMS [0xcc][0xe1][0xca][0xbe][0xd0][0xc5][0xcf][0xa2][0xa3][0xa1]</b></div>");[\r][\n]"
<< "document.write("<div style='height:130px;font-size:10pt;background:#ffffff'><br />");[\r][\n]"
<< "document.write("[0xb3][0xc9][0xb9][0xa6][0xb5][0xc7][0xc2][0xbc][0xa3][0xac][0xd5][0xfd][0xd4][0xda][0xd7][0xaa][0xcf][0xf2][0xb9][0xdc][0xc0][0xed][0xb9][0xdc][0xc0][0xed][0xd6][0xf7][0xd2][0xb3][0xa3][0xa1]");[\r][\n]"
<< "document.write("<br /><a href='/manager/index.php'>[0xc8][0xe7][0xb9][0xfb][0xc4][0xe3][0xb5][0xc4][0xe4][0xaf][0xc0][0xc0][0xc6][0xf7][0xc3][0xbb][0xb7][0xb4][0xd3][0xa6][0xa3][0xac][0xc7][0xeb][0xb5][0xe3][0xbb][0xf7][0xd5][0xe2][0xc0][0xef]...</a><br/></div>");[\r][\n]"
<< "setTimeout('JumpUrl()',1000);</script>[\r][\n]"
<< "</center>[\r][\n]"
<< "</body>[\r][\n]"
<< "</html>[\r][\n]"
Releasing connection org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager$ConnAdapter@158bc22
Get connection for route HttpRoute[{}->http://localhost]
Stale connection check
CookieSpec selected: best-match
Cookie [version: 0][name: PHPSESSID][value: kkjhvrbaoq2rbtk88f0nljaua2][domain: localhost][path: /][expiry: null] match [localhost:80/manager/index.php]
Cookie [version: 0][name: DedeUserID][value: 1][domain: localhost][path: /][expiry: Mon Mar 03 23:18:49 CST 2014] match [localhost:80/manager/index.php]
Cookie [version: 0][name: DedeUserID__ckMd5][value: e22b0794b6991249][domain: localhost][path: /][expiry: Mon Mar 03 23:18:49 CST 2014] match [localhost:80/manager/index.php]
Cookie [version: 0][name: DedeLoginTime][value: 1393773529][domain: localhost][path: /][expiry: Mon Mar 03 23:18:49 CST 2014] match [localhost:80/manager/index.php]
Cookie [version: 0][name: DedeLoginTime__ckMd5][value: 4e56d5c9755c8116][domain: localhost][path: /][expiry: Mon Mar 03 23:18:49 CST 2014] match [localhost:80/manager/index.php]
Attempt 1 to execute request
Sending request: GET /manager/index.php HTTP/1.1
>> "GET /manager/index.php HTTP/1.1[EOL]"
>> "Host: localhost[EOL]"
>> "Connection: Keep-Alive[EOL]"
>> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.0.1 (java 1.5)[EOL]"
>> "Cookie: PHPSESSID=kkjhvrbaoq2rbtk88f0nljaua2; DedeUserID=1; DedeUserID__ckMd5=e22b0794b6991249; DedeLoginTime=1393773529; DedeLoginTime__ckMd5=4e56d5c9755c8116[EOL]"
>> "Cookie2: $Version=1[EOL]"
>> "[EOL]"
>> GET /manager/index.php HTTP/1.1
>> Host: localhost
>> Connection: Keep-Alive
>> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.0.1 (java 1.5)
>> Cookie: PHPSESSID=kkjhvrbaoq2rbtk88f0nljaua2; DedeUserID=1; DedeUserID__ckMd5=e22b0794b6991249; DedeLoginTime=1393773529; DedeLoginTime__ckMd5=4e56d5c9755c8116
>> Cookie2: $Version=1
<< "HTTP/1.1 302 Found[EOL]"
<< "Date: Sun, 02 Mar 2014 15:18:49 GMT[EOL]"
<< "Server: Apache/2.2.4 (Win32) PHP/5.2.4[EOL]"
<< "X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.4[EOL]"
<< "Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT[EOL]"
<< "Cache-Control: private[EOL]"
<< "Pragma: no-cache[EOL]"
<< "location: login.php?gotopage=%2Fmanager%2Findex.php[EOL]"
<< "Content-Length: 0[EOL]"
<< "Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99[EOL]"
<< "Connection: Keep-Alive[EOL]"
<< "Content-Type: text/html; charset=gb2312[EOL]"
<< "[EOL]"
Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 302 Found
<< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
<< Date: Sun, 02 Mar 2014 15:18:49 GMT
<< Server: Apache/2.2.4 (Win32) PHP/5.2.4
<< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.4
<< Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
<< Cache-Control: private
<< Pragma: no-cache
<< location: login.php?gotopage=%2Fmanager%2Findex.php
<< Content-Length: 0
<< Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
<< Connection: Keep-Alive
<< Content-Type: text/html; charset=gb2312
Connection can be kept alive for 5000 ms
Redirect requested to location 'login.php?gotopage=%2Fmanager%2Findex.php'
Redirecting to 'http://localhost/manager/login.php?gotopage=%2Fmanager%2Findex.php' via HttpRoute[{}->http://localhost]
CookieSpec selected: best-match
Cookie [version: 0][name: PHPSESSID][value: kkjhvrbaoq2rbtk88f0nljaua2][domain: localhost][path: /][expiry: null] match [localhost:80/manager/login.php]
Cookie [version: 0][name: DedeUserID][value: 1][domain: localhost][path: /][expiry: Mon Mar 03 23:18:49 CST 2014] match [localhost:80/manager/login.php]
Cookie [version: 0][name: DedeUserID__ckMd5][value: e22b0794b6991249][domain: localhost][path: /][expiry: Mon Mar 03 23:18:49 CST 2014] match [localhost:80/manager/login.php]
Cookie [version: 0][name: DedeLoginTime][value: 1393773529][domain: localhost][path: /][expiry: Mon Mar 03 23:18:49 CST 2014] match [localhost:80/manager/login.php]
Cookie [version: 0][name: DedeLoginTime__ckMd5][value: 4e56d5c9755c8116][domain: localhost][path: /][expiry: Mon Mar 03 23:18:49 CST 2014] match [localhost:80/manager/login.php]
Attempt 2 to execute request
Sending request: GET /manager/login.php?gotopage=%2Fmanager%2Findex.php HTTP/1.1
>> "GET /manager/login.php?gotopage=%2Fmanager%2Findex.php HTTP/1.1[EOL]"
>> "Host: localhost[EOL]"
>> "Connection: Keep-Alive[EOL]"
>> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.0.1 (java 1.5)[EOL]"
>> "Cookie: PHPSESSID=kkjhvrbaoq2rbtk88f0nljaua2; DedeUserID=1; DedeUserID__ckMd5=e22b0794b6991249; DedeLoginTime=1393773529; DedeLoginTime__ckMd5=4e56d5c9755c8116[EOL]"
>> "Cookie2: $Version=1[EOL]"
>> "[EOL]"
>> GET /manager/login.php?gotopage=%2Fmanager%2Findex.php HTTP/1.1
>> Host: localhost
>> Connection: Keep-Alive
>> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.0.1 (java 1.5)
>> Cookie: PHPSESSID=kkjhvrbaoq2rbtk88f0nljaua2; DedeUserID=1; DedeUserID__ckMd5=e22b0794b6991249; DedeLoginTime=1393773529; DedeLoginTime__ckMd5=4e56d5c9755c8116
>> Cookie2: $Version=1
<< "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[EOL]"
<< "Date: Sun, 02 Mar 2014 15:18:49 GMT[EOL]"
<< "Server: Apache/2.2.4 (Win32) PHP/5.2.4[EOL]"
<< "X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.4[EOL]"
<< "Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT[EOL]"
<< "Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0[EOL]"
<< "Pragma: no-cache[EOL]"
<< "Content-Length: 2069[EOL]"
<< "Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=98[EOL]"
<< "Connection: Keep-Alive[EOL]"
<< "Content-Type: text/html; charset=gb2312[EOL]"
<< "[EOL]"
Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<< Date: Sun, 02 Mar 2014 15:18:49 GMT
<< Server: Apache/2.2.4 (Win32) PHP/5.2.4
<< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.4
<< Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
<< Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
<< Pragma: no-cache
<< Content-Length: 2069
<< Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=98
<< Connection: Keep-Alive
<< Content-Type: text/html; charset=gb2312
Connection can be kept alive for 5000 ms
<< "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">[\r][\n]"
<< "<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">[\r][\n]"
<< "<head>[\r][\n]"
<< "<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb2312">[\r][\n]"
<< "<title>[0xd6][0xaf][0xc3][0xce][0xc4][0xda][0xc8][0xdd][0xb9][0xdc][0xc0][0xed][0xcf][0xb5][0xcd][0xb3] V57_GBK</title>[\r][\n]"
<< "<link href="css/base.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />[\r][\n]"
<< "<link href="css/login.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />[\r][\n]"
<< "<script src="../include/js/jquery/jquery.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>[\r][\n]"
<< "<script type="text/javascript">[\r][\n]"
<< "$ = jQuery;[\r][\n]"
<< "function changeAuthCode() {[\r][\n]"
<< "[0x9]var num = [0x9]new Date().getTime();[\r][\n]"
<< "[0x9]var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * 10000);[\r][\n]"
<< "[0x9]num = num + rand;[\r][\n]"
<< "[0x9]$('#ver_code').css('visibility','visible');[\r][\n]"
<< "[0x9]if ($("#vdimgck")[0]) {[\r][\n]"
<< "[0x9][0x9]$("#vdimgck")[0].src = "../include/vdimgck.php?tag=" + num;[\r][\n]"
<< "[0x9]}[\r][\n]"
<< "[0x9]return false;[0x9][\r][\n]"
<< "}[\r][\n]"
<< "</script>[\r][\n]"
<< "</head>[\r][\n]"
<< "<body>[\r][\n]"
<< "<div id="login-box">[\r][\n]"
<< "   <div class="login-top"><a href="../index.php" target="_blank" title="[0xb7][0xb5][0xbb][0xd8][0xcd][0xf8][0xd5][0xbe][0xd6][0xf7][0xd2][0xb3]">[0xb7][0xb5][0xbb][0xd8][0xcd][0xf8][0xd5][0xbe][0xd6][0xf7][0xd2][0xb3]</a></div>[\r][\n]"
<< "      <div class="login-main">[\r][\n]"
<< "    <form name="form1" method="post" action="login.php">[\r][\n]"
<< "      <input type="hidden" name="gotopage" value="/manager/index.php" />[\r][\n]"
<< "      <input type="hidden" name="dopost" value="login" />[\r][\n]"
<< "      <input name='adminstyle' type='hidden' value='newdedecms' />[\r][\n]"
<< "      <dl>[\r][\n]"
<< "[0x9]   <dt>[0xd3][0xc3][0xbb][0xa7][0xc3][0xfb][0xa3][0xba]</dt>[\r][\n]"
<< "[0x9]   <dd><input type="text" name="userid"/></dd>[\r][\n]"
<< "[0x9]   <dt>[0xc3][0xdc]&nbsp;&nbsp;[0xc2][0xeb][0xa3][0xba]</dt>[\r][\n]"
<< "[0x9]   <dd><input type="password" class="alltxt" name="pwd"/></dd>[\r][\n]"
<< "[0x9]   [0x9][0x9]<dt>&nbsp;</dt>[\r][\n]"
<< "[0x9][0x9]<dd><button type="submit" name="sm1" class="login-btn" onclick="this.form.submit();">[0xb5][0xc7][0xc2][0xbc]</button></dd>[\r][\n]"
<< "[0x9] </dl>[\r][\n]"
<< "[0x9]</form>[\r][\n]"
<< "   </div>[\r][\n]"
<< "   <div class="login-power">Powered by<a href="http://www.dedecms.com" title="DedeCMS[0xb9][0xd9][0xcd][0xf8]"><strong>DedeCMSV57_GBK</strong></a>&copy; 2004-2011 <a href="http://www.desdev.cn" target="_blank">DesDev</a> Inc.</div>[\r][\n]"
<< "</div>[\r][\n]"
<< "<div class="dede-iframe"><iframe name="loginad" src="login.php?dopost=showad" frameborder="0" id="loginad" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" width="100%"></iframe></div>[\r][\n]"
<< "</body>[\r][\n]"
<< "</html>[\r][\n]"
Releasing connection org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager$ConnAdapter@5353c8
Connection shut down
```

Answer (score 0):

i got the annswer.in some case,before form posts,we need visit the page first.when we visit the page ,it will give us a sessionid.then the form and sessionid post to the server together.if we not visit the page first,we post the form directly, we can't login .